# How to correctly use h264_amf on Windows?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-processing, h.264, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to use hardware encoding with FFMPEG on Windows 10 with AMD Radeon r5 M330 DGPU on laptop : HP-AC026-TX. FFMPEG version is `5.1.2-full_build-www.gyan.dev` from [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/). I'm using this :

```
fmpeg ^
    -hide_banner ^
    -v verbose ^
    -i "%1" ^
    -c:v h264_amf -acodec copy -y out.mp4
```

but it fails with :

```
[h264_amf @ 000001fb84d80b80] AMF initialisation succeeded via D3D11.
[h264_amf @ 000001fb847ab3c0] CreateComponent(AMFVideoEncoderVCE_AVC) failed with error 36
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

The arguments seem as generic as I could hope, FFMPEG should use sensible defaults, so I can't Understand why it is failing.
Entire FFMPEG output is :

```
[h264 @ 000001fb84706c40] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1366_pngl_20220816_161558.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2022-08-16T10:51:42.000000Z
    com.android.version: 11
    com.android.capture.fps: 30.000000
  Duration: 00:03:41.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7517 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive, left), 1920x1080 (1920x1088), 7259 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.96 fps, 29.99 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-16T10:51:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-16T10:51:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_amf))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 000001fb84787400] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 000001fb84cfd780] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/90000 fr:90000/3001 sar:1/1
[h264_amf @ 000001fb84d80b80] AMF initialisation succeeded via D3D11.
[h264_amf @ 000001fb847ab3c0] CreateComponent(AMFVideoEncoderVCE_AVC) failed with error 36
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[AVIOContext @ 000001fb846f89c0] Statistics: 0 bytes written, 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 000001fb846f3f40] Statistics: 371902 bytes read, 3 seeks
Conversion failed!
```

What should I do to make hardware encoding work ?

Comment: The AMD hardware encoder is somewhat sensitive to driver and SDK version.
What version of the AMD SDK was used to build FFMPEG?
What version of the driver is running on your machine?

Comment: I get a similar error with an AMD Radeon HD 7700:

SubmitInput() failed with error 29.  Error Submitting video frame to the encoder.